# WorldClim Bioclimatic variables link broken

Tags: r

Does anyone meet the same question today?I was trying to download the standard (19) WorldClim Bioclimatic variables.

https://worldclim.org/data/worldclim21.html
https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/worldclim/v2.1/base/wc2.1_30s_bio.zip

But I cannot download it.
I have sent an email to the info@worldclim.org
This is such a great climate dataset! Thank you for maintaining it!
thank you!

@Robert Hijmans

Comment: It looks like the server might be down or something. When I try using `raster::getData("worldclim",var="bio",res=10)` or with `geodata::worldclim_country()`, it says that it could not connect to the server.

Comment: thanks! what can we do now?